# Help identify a short story about a trader who kills someone during a bar fight and is sentenced to kill fellow prisoners on a schedule, but doesn't

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm pretty sure I read this in an anthology in the 70s or 80s.  A space trader lands in a place where he knows the laws are strictly enforced and the sentences are horrific.  During a bar fight, he kills someone and after a very short trial he's sentenced to a prison (maybe a hollow asteroid?), where he is required to kill another prisoner regularly/repeatedly.  There are 2 groups of prisoners and he is to kill one from the 'other' group.  He refuses and various dire threats are levied against him, but he still refuses.  Lots of discussion with the other prisoners about what's going on and why some prisoners disappear from the prison (this is the interesting part of the story).  In the end, it turns out the system figures that if you can be persuaded to repeat your crime, then you're guilty of something, and they keep you.  If you hold out and don't repeat, they figure you're innocent and sneak you out of prison, and release you.  The 'other' prisoners (victims) are automatons that appear to be human.

Comment: Dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239784 ?