# Seeking story about prisoner having to repeat his crime as punishment

Tags: story-identification, crime

A man is in prison for manslaughter or murder, and he is expected to murder other citizens of what I seem to remember was an underground colony. I remember perpetual night and individual houses. Thieves are expected to steal things every day/night, and he's supposed to murder. I think the word "quota" is tossed around frequently.

But despite believing he'll receive terrible punishment, he can't bring himself to kill anybody, so he is brought to the warden and told he's free because he's considered "cured".

Someone pointed me to ["The Status Civilization" by Robert Sheckley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Status_Civilization), but I read it and it's not the story I'm thinking of.

Comment: I am not sure of the title, but I remember a similar story, but I do not remember its name. In order to improve the identification chances, does this ring a bell? 1. The man had killed an alien in a fight, he did not intend to it but that alien species had very weak skulls. 2. He is declared guilty by the aliens reading his mind. 3. When he is released, he is told that every possible victim in that planet was actually a robot. 4. He goes mad when knowing them and begins killing people, but since he believes they are robots the mind reading probe declares him innocent...

Comment: It's [Pariah Planet by Lloyd Biggle Jr](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239784/prison-planet-book-where-the-protagonist-is-given-a-quota-to-commit-one-murder-a). Another story already IDed on this site! :-) It has also been published as "The Perfect Punishment", but I read it under it's original title in "Worlds of Tomorrow" magazine.

Comment: Can you confirm whether "Pariah Planet" is the story you're looking for. If so we'll mark this as a duplicate of the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES!! That's the one. I asked this same question once before, as I mentioned, but that was a few years ago.

**Pariah Planet**. I will have to look for it.

Comment: If you want to post a self-answer, you should also accept it.